# Reserve space for empty JLabel

Tags: java, swing, resize, jlabel, pack

I have a JLabel for an error output. This is empty in the beginning and can be filled by some actions.
But when it's empty it won't be noticed when I pack() my JFrame. So when my error label gets content, I need to repack my frame to make it visible (and that also resizes the frame what I want to avoid).

At the moment I use

```
lError.settext(" "); // set text to space as buffer content
```

but I'm not happy with this solution.

Is there another **cleaner** way to reach my result?

Edit: I reached what I wanted by editing the size of the panel around my label with `setPreferredSize()`, but I still have this space buffer.

```
pError.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(pError.getPreferredSize().width, new JLabel(" ").getPreferredSize().height));
```

Comment: is the `lError` fixed size or can there be so much text that you need a scroller?

Comment: @MartinFrank Scrolling won't be necessary.

Comment: if you will right IError.setText(""); it will work as well. but it is null string rather then space.

Comment: For fixed size label you can set preferred size. lError.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 18));

Comment: @IrfanNasim No, it doesn't. When I set the text to null string, pack() ignores the space of the label.

Comment: when no scrolling is necessary, see @SergiyMedvynskyy... `lError.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h));`

Comment: @MartinFrank That'd be good, but I dont't want to fix my width because it could cut off my text. And when I set it to match the parent's one, it would be aligned left.

Comment: ok, i'm confused a bit ^^...  you don't want variable size (would be scroller) and you don't want fixed size? so what? ...  but obviously you want also to be another question, how to center a text in JPanel? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810581/how-to-center-the-text-in-a-jlabel where they answer with SwingConstants.CENTER (two answers there)...

Comment: @MartinFrank Oh well, I mean I don't need a scroller as a scroll bar or something like that, because my error won't be as long as my panel / frame is wide. But the width of the label should be variable.

Comment: ok, thanks for clearing that out! i think i get you now better...

Comment: i hope my pic is somehow correct?

Comment: @MartinFrank Erm, no sorry ^^ I edited my question.

Comment: well i'm glad you found your solution ^^

Comment: @MartinFrank Actually I didn't find a solution I'm glad with. I just moved my problem to a less annoying place `new JLabel(" ")` :/

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on what Layout you are using, but sometimes I've had to call not just setPreferredSize but also setMinimumSize (and setMaximumSize).

Comment: I also played with those methods, but I wasn't able to get a cleaner result than the one in my latest edit.

Comment: What layout are you using? Could you provide some more context for your code?

Comment: My pError is a `GridBagLayout()`.